# Quartz Composer using video capture output as GLSL shader environmnet

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, quartz-composer

L.S.,

A year ago I made a very simple screen saver using Quartz Composer on Snow Leopard (SL).

The screen saver captures the input of the built-in camera with the "video capture"-patch and uses the images as input for the environment parameter of the "GLSL shader"-patch as found in the GLSL Environment Map.qtz stock example. The shader in turn maps the video capture on the famous 3D teapot, creating the illusion of a chrome teapot mirroring the person in front of the iMac or MB. You can find the screen saver here: [Compresses QC source](http://www.twan.com/screensaver/mirrored_teapot.qtz.zip)

Under Mountain Lion (ML) the output of the video capture fails to function as input for the envirnment of the GLSL shader patch.

The video capture still works though. Because you can still can use it as the input for the image parameter for the teapot-patch.

Furthermore, it doesn't matter whether I run the screen saver as a screen saver or in the QC runner.

Anybody any idea what's happening? The question boils down to: Why is it under ML not possible to use the video capture output as environment for the GLSL shader patch?

The screen saver, as simpel as it is, is quite popular and it would be a shame if people can't enjoy it any more.

I'm eagerly looking forward to a solution!

Comment: did you find a way to fix this?

Comment: No @anil, but I found that the results where different for different installations of (Snow) Lion. As of yet I haven't had the opportunity to investigate it further (time etc).

Comment: hmm.I went from Snow to Mountain and cant seem to get it to work on Mountain =(